# crossdomain $.ajax and 302 redirection on safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect, safari, cross-domain

I'm having a cross-domain $.ajax call setup like

```
$.ajax({
    url         : 'http://example.com/somepage',
    type        : 'get',
    crossDomain : true,
    xhrFields   : { withCredentials: true },
    success     : function(data) {
        // do something with data
    }
});
```

and server side on the vhost conf

```
SetEnvIfNoCase ORIGIN (.*) ORIGIN=$1
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN}e"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "post, get, put, options, patch, delete"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "60"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
```

this is working fine unless my http://example.com/somepage is redirecting with a 302 code to an other page http://example.com/someotherpage, in this case ie, ff, chrome & opera are working & returning the data from the redirected to page, but not safari i can see the redirection (safari console) but the second call after redirection is aborted.

any ideas ?

Comment: I've been sorting through an issue like this right now.  The problem is Safari refusing to follow the ajax derived redirect to an external site.  If you hit the endpoint directly ( the one that should give the redirect ) it will likely work just fine.  No real answer for you yet.  I'm likely going to change my response to a 200 with something in the body that tells the front end to redirect to the url embedded within it via a window.location call.

Comment: Stupid Safari... classic Apple mentality. "cross-domain? Why would anyone ever want to be anywhere other than apple.com???"

Comment: Yes, I'm having this issue right now! It's killing me. My issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044293/xhr-ajax-requests-w-redirect-fails-w-invalidstateerror-dom-exception-11

Comment: We came across this issue yesterday, spent the whole day looking into it. No direct fix but we were lucky to have a way round doing the redirect.  We seem to have a lot of special cases in our code for safari these days, to be fair a lot more than IE it now seems

Comment: In my tests, the problem appears to be that the request to the URL doing the redirect comes back with no response (highlighted on Safari with red) and, by extension, with no response headers. That means the "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true" header is never received. From there, everything goes wrong. Since there's no such header, the browser doesn’t pass the response to JavaScript (xhr.responseText is an empty string) and triggers an error. Why all this? Somewhere in Cupertino, someone is having a laugh.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment but I cannot comment. I hope this helps you.

A while ago we had some problems with redirections due to CORS usage in Safari.

Safari aborts the request because it does a pre-flight request before and maybe the config was/is not adequate.

I would try the following (it worked for us):

supportedHeaders:
**pageSuccess,pageError,pageLogin,Origin,Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding**

supportedMethods:
**GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS**

exposedHeaders:
pageSuccess, pageError, pageLogin

Also allow subdomains, supported credentials and allow generic http requests should be set to **true**.

We exposed some other info in the headers giving values of true/false (see exposedHeaders and supportedHeaders) Like ErrorPage or SuccesPage and when these were present on the response we get them  using  **jqXHR.getResponseHeader('erroPage')**  in order to perform the redirections.

Here you will find a couple of usefull links:

- http://zacstewart.com/2012/04/14/http-options-method.html
- https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/
- http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html
- http://enable-cors.org/resources.html

Regards.

Ps. You config seems to be almost the same as ours. There are only differences on the supportedHeaders (and of course the exposedHeaders added specially for our case)