# Safari xhr (AJAX) requests w/ cross-domain redirect fails

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest, cors, http-status-code-302

How to reproduce the issue

1. Make an AJAX request to a server using Safari
2. Have the server response w/ 302 to a different domain

If either of those conditions is ***not*** met, it works.

1. Use a different browser, it works.
2. Have the server redirect to same domain, it works.

.

```
Load: function (in_url, in_cb, in_responseType) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', in_url, true);
  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      in_cb(null, xhr.response);
    } else {
      in_cb(new Error('[Loader] Could not fetch from: '+in_url+', status: '+xhr.status));
    }
  };
  xhr.onerror = function (error) {
    in_cb(error);
  };

  xhr.send();
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a known issue with Safari. It seems like it's actually being worked on as of recently https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112471.

Comment: Nevertheless make sure your server supports CORS

Answer (score 1):

This [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044293/safari-xhr-ajax-requests-w-cross-domain-redirect-fails#comment64736705_33044293) was fixed.
Safari 10.1 (WebKit 603.1.30) was the first version not affected.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I asked so long ago I no longer have the code lying around to test. If someone can confirm that it's fixed I will mark your response as correct